# A predictably random shuffeling of input lines with bash's `$RANDOM` doesn't work

Tags: bash, random-number-generator

I have an input of about 100 lines. I want to shuffle them "randomly", but I want to control it. i.e. I want to seed the random number generator to always produce the same ordering.

I thought I could use `bash(1)'s` `$RANDOM` variable, but this always produces different output. What's wrong?

```
RANDOM=1 cat myfile | while read LINE ; do echo "$RANDOM $LINE" ; done | sort
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline consists of 3 different processes, so you need to seed `RANDOM` in the appropriate one:

```sh
cat myfile | 
(RANDOM=1; while read LINE ; do echo "$RANDOM $LINE" ; done ) |
sort
```

Comment: Works perfectly.